# Missing record in Access Web App

Tags: ms-access-web-app

I have a basic Access Web App that I'm using. There is a Biography table that has a bunch of fields, including a PartnerName field. The PartnerName field is a lookup field connected to a Names table with just 2 fields (NameID, Name).

When I edit a name in the Name table it appears to delete the associated record in some of the biography online views (Summary, List). However, the record it is still there in the datasheet on the Access client and the Datasheet View online.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please share the relevant code so people can offer suggestions/help.

Answer (score 0):

If your situation is:

```
Biography
---------
PartnerName
X
Y
Z

Names
-----
NameID  Name
1       X
2       Y
3       Z
```

Then based on your description, I expect that your "biography online views" would display all three Biography records; that's because they each correspond to a record in the Names table.

Now, when you change a Name in the Names table from "X" to "Joe", for example, your "biography online view" might not display the "X" biography any longer - it might look like it's "deleted" to use your words.  That would be because the Biography "X" no longer corresponds to a record in the Names table.

If what you want - that is, if what you are expecting to see in your "biography online view - is to see all Biography records even if they don't match with a record in Names - then it's possible that whoever is maintaining the query for your "biography online views" could change the query to use an OUTER join against the Names table instead of the INNER join they might be using.

From [Mark Harrison's answer to Difference between Inner and Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

- An inner join of A and B gives the result of A intersect B, i.e. the
  inner part of a Venn diagram intersection.
- An outer join of A and B gives the results of A union B, i.e. the
  outer parts of a Venn diagram union.

If the query is selecting from the Biography table, you'd want a LEFT OUTER JOIN in order to get all rows of Biography (regardless of whether they match a record in Names) plus common rows of Names.